# Retrieve single element from LINQ query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

Working with LINQ for the first time in a while and trying to clean something up.  I have the following statements:

```
var element = await _Entities.References
    .Where(db => db.LoadId == request.LoadId && db.ReferenceCode == "123")
    .OrderByDescending(rec => rec.Created).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (element != null) {
       dto.ElementValue = element.Value;
    }
```

I'd like to condense this into a single statement if possible but I was having trouble getting just the value from the await method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
dto.ElementValue = (await _Entity.References
    .Where(db => db.LoadId == request.LoadId && db.ReferenceCode == "123")
    .OrderByDescending(rec => rec.Created)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken))?.Value 
    ?? dto.ElementValue;
```

Note that technically this changes the behaviour of the code. Previously, if the query doesn't return a result, the `ElementValue` property is not touched. With a one-liner, if the query doesn't return a result, the `ElementValue` getter and setter will both be called.

Also, if the query returns a result whose `Value` is `null`, the `ElementValue` property will be set to itself rather than `null`.